# Ctypes mozilla unknown error

Tags: firefox-addon, jsctypes

In a mozille extension I run:

```
SecSess.Logger.info("ctypes test");
Components.utils.import("resource://gre/modules/ctypes.jsm");
SecSess.Logger.info("1");
this.lib = ctypes.open("libcrypto.so");
SecSess.Logger.info("2");
var a = new Uint8Array(1<<10);  
SecSess.Logger.info("3");
var ptr = new ctypes.uint8_t.ptr(a.buffer);
SecSess.Logger.info("4");
```

Why this ugly logging after each step you might ask? Well this code fails without showing me an error. (or at least I can't find the error message)

This is printed:

```
ctypes test
1
2
3
```

So the 5th log message is never printed which means the following statement never completes:

```
var ptr = new ctypes.uint8_t.ptr(a.buffer);
```

This is a simplified version of some old code I have to work with and which I also found online as being valid. However it doesn't work. This add-on wasn't developped using the new SDK with jpm. Quite frankly I don't know how and when it was developped but I need to run some tests on it. It comes with a few source files ordered in a components and a modules directory and a chrome.manifest and install.rdf in the root. I copied these files to the extension directory of Mozilla in order for it to work. The extension executes but there seems to be a problem with ctypes. Aren't ctypes fully supported anymore or are these old style add-on no longer valid for the modern Firefox?

Regards,

Roel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think they landed a a patch to disallow making a pointer from buffers. I'll double check.

Edit:
Ah per this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/js-ctypes/Using_js-ctypes/Working_with_ArrayBuffers, you don't have to wrap it with a `ctypes.uint8_t.ptr` just pass it like `a.buffer` to wherever you need it. :)